# Объясните пожалуйста как работает это условие

Tags: java

Как работает данное условие? `z > 0` - понятно
А вот как работает `(z & (z - 1)) == 0)` - непонятно. Если мы вводим `z = 8`
То получается `( 8 & 7) == 0`, моя idea в дебаге показывается что `8 & 7 = 0` и условие верное. Собственно как так то? А если `z = 7` , то `(7 & 6)` будет 6 и 6 == 0 уже false и условие не выполняется, как это работает то???
P.s. задача заключается в том чтобы проверять является ли число степенью двойки

```
if ((z > 0) && ((z & (z - 1)) == 0)) {
            System.out.println("+"); // Число является степенью двойки
        }
```

Comment: java bitwise and - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть 2^m - наибольшая степень двойки, не превосходящая z.

Если 2^m == z, то рассмотрев побитовые записи z и z - 1 легко заметить, что их побитовое И равно нулю.

Если же z > 2^m, то z - 1 >= 2^m, а следовательно эти числа совпадают хотя бы в своем первом единичном бите, который и соответствует числу 2^m.

Таким образом, приведенное вами условие действительно проверяет, является ли z степенью двойки.

Answer (score 3):

В двоичном представлении числа, являющегося степенью двойки, всего одна единица, остальные - нули. После вычитания единицы эта единственная единичка превратится в ноль, а все более низкие разряды станут единицами. Побитовое `and` с исходным числом даст нули для всех разрядов.

```
z     = 32 : 00100000
z - 1 = 31 : 00011111
---------------------
z & (z - 1): 00000000
```